# Sending SMS through external device

Tags: c#, sms

Is there anyway to send SMS on mobile numbers through external device(modem) in C#?
I am building a school management application in which I want to use announcement function that will send one announcement to all the phone numbers in database.

Pardon me for language. English is not my native language 
Thank you in adnvance

Comment: Specifically on a modem?  Or were you just generalizing?  Have you looked at https://www.twilio.com/sms ?

Comment: you can use sms gateway api in your project.

Comment: Not on a specific device but generally